# Likelihood ratio test: $f(x)=2x$ vs $f(x)=3x^2$: $2n$ degrees of freedom?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Suppose $X_1, . . . , X_n$ are i.i.d. with pdf $f(·)$.
We want to test the hypotheses
\begin{align}
H_0 &: f(x) = 2x , \;\, \text{ for } 0 \le x \le 1, \text{ against}, \\
H_1 &: f(x) = 3x^2 , \text{ for } 0\le x \le 1.
\end{align}

Show that the level-$\alpha$ likelihood ratio test is of the form:
$$
\text{reject }H_0 \text{ if } T_n \le c_{n,α},
$$
where $T_n$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom.

The likelihood ratio is
$$
\lambda = \frac{\prod f_0(x_i)}{\prod f_1(x_i)} = 
\frac{(2/3)^n}{t^n},
$$
with $t=\prod x_i$.
Then I should show
$$
T_n = -2\ln \lambda \sim \chi^2(2n),
$$
I guess asymptotically.
How can the degree of freedom be $2n$?
I don't see any parameter in $H_0$ and $H_1$, to apply the theorem which says
$$
-2\ln \lambda \sim \chi^2(\#\Theta_1-\#\Theta_0).
$$

I asked on [mathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312997/14108), but the question is still unresolved.

Comment: Wait ... there are no estimated parameters under either hypothesis? To apply the [LRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) don't you need the null to be a special case of the alternative?

Comment: @Glen: No. These are both point hypotheses.

Comment: **Hint**: What is the distribution under the null of $-\log X_i$?

Comment: It is better to flag your question on math.SE and ask that it be migrated here.

Comment: To add to cardinal's hint, an exponential random variable $X$ is proportional to a $\chi^2$ random variable with two degrees of freedom, and that's where the question-setter is getting the $2n$ degrees of freedom. A couple of other comments: your likelihood ratio should be $\frac{(2/3)^n}{t}$, not $\frac{(2/3)^n}{t^n}$ where $t = \prod_i x_i$, or better yet, $\frac{t}{(2/3)^n}$ since the likelihood ratio is usually defined as $$\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}, ~~\text{not as}~ \frac{f_0(x)}{f_1(x)}$$ the way you have it.

Comment: Dear @Dilip: (+1) But, just a note, both conventions are commonly used in the statistical literature regarding the likelihood ratio. In this case, since we are rejecting for *small* $T_n$, we can see that is consistent with the way it is given in the question, i.e., $f_0 / f_1$.

Comment: Of course, you get the same answer whichever convention you use. :-)

Comment: @cardinal I take it the first sentence of the wikipedia article I linked to is wrong, since it explicitly states that.

Comment: Actually, the LR test is also of the form $U_n \le c'_{n,\alpha}$ where $U_n$ has *any* continuous distribution you please: merely apply an appropriate strictly monotonic increasing function to $T_n$ and adjust $c'_{n,\alpha}$ accordingly. In this sense the question is almost without content.

Comment: @Glen_b: I would say that article, in general, is a bit of a mess. The first sentence of that article (as it currently read) is not wrong, *per se*, it's just unnecessarily narrow, especially considering that the Neyman-Pearson lemma can be used as a foundation for building up and motivating the theory. :)